# Почему модальное окно не открывается?

Tags: javascript

Вызываю модальное окно по кнопке:

```
<a href="#modal-order-service" data-toggle="modal" class="btn order_btn">

$('.order_btn').on('click', function() {
document.getElementById('order').reset();
$('#tmp_block').html($('.polomka').html()+$('.total').html());
var text = $('#tmp_block');
text.find('.del').remove();
text.find('.basket').remove();
console.log(text.html());

$('#modal-order-service #order').append('<input type="hidden" class="calc_text" name="order" value="'+text.text()+'" />');
return false; });
```

Но окно не открывается, в чем ошибка?

Окно:

```
<div id="modal-order-service" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog call_modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <form id="order">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>

                <h4 class="modal-title">Оформить заказ</h4>
                <p class="after-modal-title text-center">Оставьте свои данные и наши менеджеры свяжутся с вами для уточнения деталей</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" name="uname" class="form-control" placeholder="Ваше имя" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="email" name="uemail" class="form-control" placeholder="Ваш E-mail" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" name="uphone" class="form-control phone-mask" placeholder="+7 (999) 999-99-99" required>
                </div>
                <input name="formInfo" class="formInfo" type="hidden" value="Заявка на настройку"/>
                <!-- DIV - в котором выводится блок с recaptcha -->
                <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LcZYdgUAAAAAJbMEwPOTUjlkDcjlue-fdUYItxX" data-theme="light" style="width: max-content;margin: auto;"></div>
                <input type="hidden" name="formData" value="">
                <button type="submit" class="btn main-btn form-btn">Перезвоните мне</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: return false - вот из за этого.

Comment: @adudnik.ru спасибо!